# Ember build and sourcemaps

Tags: ember.js

My Ember app is actually a child engine. Recently, I observed that the source maps are not working properly in Chrome. So, I have to open the generated engine.js to debug…Instead I want to be able to open the individual source modules/files written in ES6 using Ctrl + P in Chrome Sources and add breakpoints to debug.

I tried both the ways in ember-cli-build.js;

```
babel: { sourceMaps: ‘inline’ }

sourcemaps: { enabled: true, extensions: [‘js’] }
```

My question is am I doing something wrong with the above? Does the parent/host app have any impact on the generated source map OR is the child engine configuration for sourcemap totally independent of the parent config ?

Comment: Could you explain more in detail what issue you are facing? Is the source map not generated at all? Or is it not matching the actual code? Or is it not correctly linked to the code?

Comment: So the sourcemap is generated...However, I am unable to open individual modules in Chrome Sources like I was able to earlier...

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Do you have a repository to reproduce?